# Flume. Sink kite.Dataset, kerberos hdfs

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

История следующая:
Есть флюмовый конфиг, в нем синк пишет в hdfs. Hadoop с kerberos.
При первом запуске флюма всё подключается и работает, но как только тикет истекает он его не продливает автоматически. И получается, что работает только за счет перезапуск.
Но мне кажется я что-то упустил и так не должно работать.
Ну и соответственно в самом синке указан принципал и путь к кейтабу.
Flume Apache 1.8.0